# re-query window size upon resizing

Tags: jquery, resize, width

I'm a bit stuck here. I have the following script which takes the window width and created a beautiful 100% width slider. However, when I refresh, it uses the original window width, so it will e.g. show the original 600px instead of the new 700px width. Any idea how I can query the window upon resizing? I can't seem to get it to work.

```
//current position
var pos = 0;
//number of slides
var totalSlides = $('#slider-wrap ul li').length;
//get the slide width
var sliderWidth = $('#slider-wrap').width();


$(document).ready(function(){


/*****************
 BUILD THE SLIDER
*****************/
//set width to be 'x' times the number of slides
$('#slider-wrap ul#slider').width(sliderWidth*totalSlides);
```

Comment: you can use the resize event

Comment: when I add the resize event it only reads the resize, but document ready no longer works. Any tips on combining both? Sorry newby JS-wise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a `$(window).resize(function(){location.reload();});`

Answer (score 0):

You can get window's width while resizing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      windowWidth  = $(window).width();
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm probably silly, but I can only either do the resize or the document ready... but can't seem to combine it.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, this might be what you want?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Still doesn't seem to work, but I think I'm just missing something here... thanks for trying to help though. Much appreciated.

 https://remcovanessen.co.uk/lb